# merge to array in ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def get_firstArray
    a = Array.new(5)

    number =Array.new(5){ |index| index * 2 }
    return  print number
    puts
end
def get_secondtArray
    a = Array.new(4)

    number =A rray.new(4){ |index| index * 3 }
    return print number
    puts
end
a = get_firstArray
b = get_secondtArray

def merge(a, b)

    mer= a.concat b
     return mer
end
```

Output 
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8][0, 3, 6, 9]

I need the output like [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9]
with sorte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.concat(b)` will forever change `a`.

Instead you can let `merge` return a new array containing the union of `a` and `b`

```
def get_first_array
  Array.new(5) {|index| index * 2 }
end

def get_second_array
  Array.new(4) {|index| index * 3 }
end

def merge(a, b)
  (a+b).sort
end

a = get_first_array    # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
b = get_second_array   # [0, 3, 6, 9]

c = merge(a, b)        # [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Work for me :) this time

Answer (score 1):

The [`print` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print) returns `nil` so you you want to return `number` not `print number`. Nothing after `return` is executed, so you can remove the `puts` at the end of the methods. A method returns the result of the last statement automatically, so you don't need the `return` or the `number` variable. You're creating the array twice in the methods, so we can get rid of the first one. You're never calling the `merge` method, which also doesn't need a `return` statement. The method names aren't standard camel case, i.e., something like `get_first_array` would match the Ruby standard. You're never sorting the merged array. Putting those together, you end up with something like:

```
def evens
  Array.new(5) { |index| index * 2 }
end

def triples
  Array.new(4) { |index| index * 3 }
end

e = evens
t = triples

def merge(a, b)
  a.concat b
end
puts merge(e, t).sort
```

As a side note, here's how I would write this from scratch (main difference is not using methods for one-liners:

```
evens = (0..4).map { |n| n * 2 }
triples = (0..3).map { |n| n * 3 }
puts (evens + triples).sort
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_first_array
  Array.new(5) {|index| index * 2 }
end

def get_second_array
  Array.new(4) {|index| index * 3 }
end

def merge(a, b)
  (a+b).sort
end

a = get_first_array   
b = get_second_array   

c = merge(a, b)

print c
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem boils down to one of combining sorted arrays `a` and `b` in such a way that the resulting array is sorted. A natural solution is `(a+b).sort`, but this is relatively inefficient, considering that `a` and `b` are already sorted. Merging two sorted arrays must be a fairly common requirement, so I gave some thought to how that could be done efficiently.

The way I settled on is very straightforward (which was somewhat of a disappointment); there may well be better (or at least cleaner) algorithms that I'm not aware of. Incidentally, I gave some thought as to whether `Enumerable#slice_before` could be used to advantage, but came up empty.

```
def merge_sorted(a,b)
  sa, sb = a.size, b.size
  ia = ib = 0
  c = []
  loop do
    (return c + a[ia..-1]) if (ib == sb)
    (return c + b[ib..-1]) if (ia == sa)
    if a[ia] < b[ib]
      c << a[ia]
      ia += 1
    else
      c << b[ib]
      ib += 1
    end
  end
end

merge_sorted([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9])
  #=> [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

As  def merge_sorted(a,b)
      sa, sb = a.size, b.size
      ia = ib = 0
      c = []
      loop do
        (return c + a[ia..-1]) if (ib == sb)
        (return c + b[ib..-1]) if (ia == sa)
        if a[ia] < b[ib]
          c << a[ia]
          ia += 1
        else
          c << b[ib]
          ib += 1
        end
      end
    end

```
merge_sorted([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9])
  #=> [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```